# Return certain vertices and whether they share an edge with a particular vertex

Tags: titan, gremlin

I'm trying to model follower relationships between certain users in my app:

user----follows----user

(think Twitter)

Given a set of userIds I need to return all those user vertices and a boolean if a particular user (`currentUser`) has a `follows` edge to those users. So I need to know whether or not `currentUser` is following each of these users:

> user1: true
>
> user2: true
>
> user3: false
>
> user4: true

I'm stuck on how to fetch that follow status. If I return each user vertex like so:

`currentUser = g.V(1);
g.V().hasLabel("appUser").or(__.has("userId","123869681319429"),
                             __.has("userId","103659593341656")).valueMap();`

what would be an efficient command to determine if each of those had an incoming `follows` edge from `currentUser`?

TitanDB 1.0.0 running on DynamoDB.

Edit- Adding My full working traversal:

`g.V().hasLabel('appUser').or(__.has('cId', '1232'),__.has('cId', '1116')).group().by().by(__.in('follows').hasId(hasLabel('appUser').has('pId', 'd13dfa6').id()).count())`

Edit 2 - 
I wound up rewriting this traversal to better capture the data I needed by using `as()` and `select()`. Leaving here for reference:

`g.V().hasLabel('appUser').or(__.has('cId', '1232'),__.has('cId', '1116')).as('user','followCount').select('user','followCount').by(__.valueMap()).by(__.in('follows').hasId(hasLabel('appUser').has('pId', 'd13dfa6').id()).count())`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to do it.  Assume this sample graph:

```
gremlin> graph = TinkerGraph.open()
==>tinkergraph[vertices:0 edges:0]
gremlin> vUser1 = graph.addVertex(id,1)
==>v[1]
gremlin> vUser2 = graph.addVertex(id,2)
==>v[2]
gremlin> vUser3 = graph.addVertex(id,3)
==>v[3]
gremlin> vUser1.addEdge('follows',vUser2)
==>e[0][1-follows->2]
gremlin> vUser3.addEdge('follows',vUser3)
==>e[1][3-follows->3]
```

Your code snippet above demonstrates that you will have the "current user" vertex and the vertices of the users you want to compare to that current user to see if there are any follows relationships.  Given that assumption, you could approach it this way:

```
gremlin> g = graph.traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:3 edges:2], standard]
gremlin> g.V(vUser2,vUser3).group().by().by(__.in("follows").hasId(vUser1.id()).count())
==>[v[2]:1, v[3]:0]
```

In this case, you iterate the list of user vertices you want to compare against, then group on them. The traversal will output a `Map` where a value greater than `0` represents a follows relationship and a value of zero represents the opposite of no follow relationship. So, in the example above, user 1 follows 2 but doesn't follow 3.

Comment: Thank you, this works well. I've added my full working traversal to the original question. As you can see I'm looking up users based on an ID and then incorporating your logic. Is it possible to return certain properties of the looked up users (firstName, lastName, etc) instead of the entire objects? I'm not sure where I could specify those properties.

Comment: The first `by()` modulator specifies the key for the map. You could pass it the property to pull out, or maybe `valueMap()` based `Traversal` to pop-off the properties.  I think `Map` equality would still allow it to group properly with a `Map` as the key.  You could also post process the result to transform the `Vertex` keys to whatever you want. There's a lot of options.

Comment: Passing an individual property to `by()` works great but I suppose I can only return a single property this way. I tried `.by(__.valueMap())` but that yields `org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.BulkSet cannot be cast to org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.Element`. Am I passing that correctly? I'm trying to avoid any post processing if possible for performance reasons.